# How to set up and enhance bugzilla response speed

Tags: bugzilla

Successful installation of bugzilla. but bugzilla page (every page) response is very slow, how to set up?

Server Platform: 
LAMP+Debian 6

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using mod_perl yet, but if not, you should try it. It really increases the response time when using Apache. 
Here is more about it http://perl.apache.org/